# How does the kernel Makefile magically knows what to compile?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, device-driver, linux-device-driver, kernel

I'm new in writing Linux device driver, and I'm wondering how the kernel `Makefile` magically knows what to compile. To illustrate what I don't understand, consider the following case:

I did a `#include <linux/irq.h>` in my driver code and I'm able to find the header file `irq.h` in the kernel directory `KDIR/include/linux`. However, this is only the header file, so I thought the `irq.c` source code must be out there somewhere. Hence, I looked into the `KDIR/arch/arm` searching for `irq.c` (since I'm using the ARM architecture). My confusion begins here when I found really many `irq.c` inside `KDIR/arch/arm`. To simply list a few, I got:

- KDIR/arch/arm/mach-at91/irq.c
- KDIR/arch/arm/mach-davinci/irq.c
- KDIR/arch/arm/mach-omap1/irq.c
- KDIR/arch/arm/mach-orion5x/irq.c
- many more...

In my `Makefile`, I have a line like this:

```
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- ARCH=arm modules
```

So I understand that the kernel `Makefile` knows that I'm using the ARM architecture, but under `KDIR/arch/arm/`, there are so many `irq.c` with the same name. I'm guessing that the `mach-davinci/irq.c` is compiled since davinci is the cpu name I'm using. But then, how can the kernel `Makefile` knows this is the one to compile? Or if I would like to have a look for the `irq.c` that I'm actually using, which one should I refer to?

I believe there must be a way to know this besides reading the long kernel `Makefile`. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond the ARCH variable, you can also choose the system type (mach) from the configuration menu (there is actually a sub-menu called "System type" when you type `make menuconfig` for instance). This selection will include and compile all files under linux2.6/arch/$ARCH/mach-$MACH, and in your case this is how only one irq.c gets compiled.

That aside, it is interesting to understand how the kernel chooses which files to compile. The mechanism behind this is called Kconfig, and it is what allows you to precisely configure your kernel using `make menuconfig` and others, to compile a module from the outside like you are doing, and to select the right files to compile from simple Makefiles. While it is simple to use, its internals are rather complex - but this article, although rather old, explains it rather well:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6568

Answer (score 1):

To make a very long story short, there's a target `make config`, which you can trace. That one generates `.config`, that is your main guideline to making dependencies and controlling what will be compiled, what not, what as module and what will be compiled into the kernel.

[This guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html) should give you a basic understanding of building a kernel module (and I assume that's where you want to start with your driver).